# Core Data: three or more table joins

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

In a database I have a following situation, `A` has many `B`'s and `C` also has many `B`'s. 
What is the effective way of using Core Data relationships to search for this type of query?

1. I need to search on both `a.x` and `c.y` attributes
2. then I need those `B`'s which are common to both

For example:

`records are separated by colon (";"), and attributes by comma (",")`

```
A = {a;b}
C = {m;n}
B = {1,a,m;2,a,n;3,a,n;4,b,m;5,b,m;6,a,m;7,b,n;8,b,n}
```

Will the queries `c.x = m` and `a.y = a` result in following records from `B = {1;6}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technical note: Core Data isn't a relational database, so doesn't really have 'joins'. It's more accurately described as an object graph.

It should be quite straightforward to implement what you want:

Set up a model with entities `A`, `B`, `C`.

`B` has a 'to-many' relationship to `A` (this property called `a`), and a 'to-many' relationship to `C` (this property called `c`).

Populate this model with data as appropriate.

Then to get your 'join', search using a predicate as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"B" inManagedObjectContext:del.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSString* predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a.x = %@ AND b.y = %@", 
                        @"something1", @"something2"];

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray* objects = [del.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

See also [iPhone CoreData join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458245/iphone-coredata-join).

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I think there should be a proper guide which help the guys like me when they move from database to core data, as in core data it's all about objects only, and my problem was I was kept thinking in terms of joins. If you know any good resource about it, then please let me know

Comment: CocoaNoob, this article is quite a nice comparison: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html
Also google for things like "core data versus relational database".
Would you consider accepting my answer if you found it to be the best, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but at least I can answer how to get those objects that two Core Data managed objects have in common in a certain property.

You have two Core Data entities, `A` and `C`. As all Core Data entities, they are represented by `NSManagedObject` instances at runtime. You have defined `A` and `C` to each have a relationship called `B`, which is one-to-many or many-to-many. In other words, each `A` object can have many `B` objects and so can `C`.

To make this a bit easier I will come up with other names for these classes:

```
Dessert <<---->> Ingredient
MainDish <<---->> Ingredient
```

Let's say the relationship is called `ingredients`. You can then get all ingredients for a dessert with

```
NSSet* dessertIngredients = [myDessert valueForKey:@"ingredients"];
```

And likewise get the ingredients for the main dish like so:

```
NSSet* mainDishIngredients = [myMainDish valueForKey:@"ingredients"];
```

To get the intersection of the two sets, you need to use a mutable set object:

```
NSMutableSet* commonIngredients = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:dessertIngredients];
[commonIngredients intersectSet:mainDishIngredients];
```

Another way to get the same result is by using Cocoa's [KVC collection operator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) `@distinctUnionOfArrays`:

```
NSArray* objectsWithIngredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myMainDish, myDessert, anotherMainDish, nil];
NSSet* uniqueIngredients = [anotherMainDish valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.ingredients"];
```

Comment: Why not use a predicate containing an 'AND' and let Core Data do the heavy lifting? Then there's no need to mess around with set intersections.

Comment: You're right. I only partially understood the question, and didn't think about using the inverse relationship anyway, which is clearly better.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, your approach is also good, and easy to understand, but I think predicate search with core data will be more efficient.

Comment: Hey cocoaNoob, would you consider accepting my answer instead, if you believe it to be the best one?

Comment: @cocoaNoob: For the sake of other users, please accept the answer that you think is actually the best one, as occulus said. In this case, I think we all agree it's his answer.

Comment: Sorry, for replying late, I have made the correction, thank you guys