# iPhone: CoreData join

Tags: iphone, core-data

My question similar to question [iPhone CoreData join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2458245/602011). The difference is that I need to get all LanguageSets from a database for a given category.categoryName. How predicate will looks like ?  Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume its the same schema an you are fetching `LanguageEntry`. You can assign a predicate to the fetch request like

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.categoryName==%@",<given name>];
```

Since you want only the `LanguageSet` , you should specify so in the fetch request

```
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"languageSet"]];
```

Don't forget to set resultType as NSDictionaryResultType.