# Loop optimization / CoreData optimization

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data

Is there any way to optimise the looping in array? I have 10,000 objects in array [arr], so loop will continue to 10k times I have to make relationship between CfgBarCodeMask and CfgBarCodeMaskDetails. It takes around 8 min. How to reduce this time?

```
NSArray *arr=[coreDataEngine  fetchObjectWithEntityName:@"CfgBarCodeMask" withPredicate:nil withSortDescriptor:nil error:nil ];
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"barCodeMaskId == $idVar"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];

[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CfgBarCodeMask *barcodeMask, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
{                
    NSDictionary *variables = @{ @"idVar" : barcodeMask.id1 };

    NSArray *destinationArray=
        [coreDataEngine fetchObjectWithEntityName:@"CfgBarCodeMaskDetail" 
                                    withPredicate:[predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:variables] 
                               withSortDescriptor:nil error:nil ];

    if ([destinationArray count] >0 ) {
        [barcodeMask addMaskDetails:[NSSet setWithArray:destinationArray]];
    }           
}];
```

Comment: first step: use instruments to get a clue about which part of your code consumes most of the time

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a "join" and let core data do the matching for you. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458245/iphone-coredata-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use divide the loop into multiple batches. Each batch processes about 2000 objects, and use an concurrent NSManagedObjectContext to perform all the patches parallel. That what I did when migrating 600K objects from another database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have something like this

```
// Create concurency managed object context in your core data engine
_managedObject = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[_managedObject setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_psCoordinator];
[_managedObject setUndoManager:nil];


// Batch1
NSPredicate *predicate = //create predicate to get object 1-2000
NSArray *arr=[coreDataEngine  fetchObjectWithEntityName:@"CfgBarCodeMask" withPredicate:predicate withSortDescriptor:nil error:nil];
[self processObjects:arr];

// Batch2
predicate = //create predicate to get object 2000-4000
arr=[coreDataEngine  fetchObjectWithEntityName:@"CfgBarCodeMask" withPredicate:predicate withSortDescriptor:nil error:nil];
[self processObjects:arr];

// Batch3
predicate = //create predicate to get object 4000-6000
arr=[coreDataEngine  fetchObjectWithEntityName:@"CfgBarCodeMask" withPredicate:predicate withSortDescriptor:nil error:nil];
[self processObjects:arr];

// Batch4
predicate = //create predicate to get object 6K-8K
arr=[coreDataEngine  fetchObjectWithEntityName:@"CfgBarCodeMask" withPredicate:predicate withSortDescriptor:nil error:nil];
[self processObjects:arr];

// Batch5
predicate = //create predicate to get object 8K-10K
arr=[coreDataEngine  fetchObjectWithEntityName:@"CfgBarCodeMask" withPredicate:predicate withSortDescriptor:nil error:nil];
[self processObjects:arr];


(void)processObjects:(NSArray) objects
{
    [_managedObject performBlock: {
        NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"barCodeMaskId == $idVar"];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
        [arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CfgBarCodeMask *barcodeMask, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
        {                
            NSDictionary *variables = @{ @"idVar" : barcodeMask.id1 };

            NSArray *destinationArray=
                [coreDataEngine fetchObjectWithEntityName:@"CfgBarCodeMaskDetail" 
                                            withPredicate:[predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:variables] 
                                       withSortDescriptor:nil error:nil ];

            if ([destinationArray count] >0 ) {
                [barcodeMask addMaskDetails:[NSSet setWithArray:destinationArray]];
            }           
        }];
        [_managedObject save:nil];
    }];
}
```